# Rails 4 Dynamic Subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

Hi I am following the tutorial at http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3 and trying to make it work for rails 4. The problem I encountered is in the my controller and with the find_by_subdomain! tag, I have read that most of the the find_by methods where taken out of rails 4, and was wondering what the work around was.

my controller currently looks like

```
def set_city
  @city = City.friendly.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
end
```

and the error I am getting is

```
undefined method `find_by_subdomain!'
```

Also in case it helps my routes currently look like

```
  get '/' => 'cities#show', :constraints => { :subdomain => /.+/ }
```

Any help would by greatly appreciated and I would be happy to clarify if needed.

Comment: Hi and thank you tybro0103,
friendly is from the freidnly_id gem and I believe lets me use the slug instead of an id to call an object. 

The end solution for me was 

@city = City.find_by slug: request.subdomain

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `find_by_*` method is on the class itself:

```
City.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
```

What is `City.friendly` returning? Whatever it is, I doubt it's the `City` class.

Also, you can use `find_by` with a hash now:

```
City.find_by subdomain: request.subdomain
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object